# Can default expressions reference other inputs in a function declaration?

Tags: function, modelica, openmodelica, systemmodeler

In Modelica **I want to implement a `function` called `clip`** that works similiar to [`Clip`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip.html?q=Clip) in the Wolfram Language. That is the function will take a list of values `x` and return a vector `y` of the same length where for each component we have a **piecewise function**:

```
y_i := x_i for min ≤ x_i ≤ max, v_min for x_i < min, and v_max for x_i > max
```

So we **should see the following results**:

```
clip( {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3} , {-2,2} )           // { -2, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 2 }
clip( {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3} , {-2,2}, {-10,10} ) // { -10, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 10 }
clip( {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3} )                    // { -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1 }
```

**My approach** is the following:

```
function clip "Clip values so they do not extend beyond a given interval"
    input Real x[:] "List of values to be clipped";
    input Real[2] x_range := {-1, 1} "Original range [min,max] given as a list (default = {-1,1})";
    input Real[2] extremes := x_range "Extreme values [v_min, v_max] given as a list (default {min,max})";
    output Real y[size(x, 1)] "Clipped values";
protected
    Integer n := size(x, 1) "Length of the input vector x";
algorithm
    for i in 1:n loop
        y[i] := if x[i] < x_range[1] then extremes[1] elseif x[i] > x_range[2] then extremes[2] else x[i];
    end for;
end clip;
```

Note, that here the default expression for `extremes` references the input `x_range` which itself has the default expression `{-1, 1}`.

Unfortunately, I am getting *wrong results in Wolfram SystemModeler* 12.0 and *in OpenModelica* (OMEdit v.1.13.2) *it won't even compile*.

**My questions are:**

1. Is the above function legal Modelica code according to specs?
2. Regardless of (1.) is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes it is legal. That the defaults of inputs depend on other inputs etc is explicitly allowed by the Modelica specification.

https://specification.modelica.org/master/Ch12.html#positional-or-named-input-arguments-of-functions

> The default values may depend on other inputs (these dependencies must
>   be acyclical in the function) – the values for those other inputs will
>   then be substituted into the default values (this process may be
>   repeated if the default value for that input depend on another input).
>   The default values for inputs may not depend on non-input variables in
>   the function.

2. I haven't checked alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, for pointing this out - and obviously one would not need an alternative then. I just realize, that assignments have been changed to equations as of now?

Comment: Yes assignments are deprecated for bindings, although both work. That was specified earlier as well, but not used in the specification itself - https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaSpecification/issues/2249

Answer (score 1):

2. Array construction can be used instead of the for-loop:

   y := {if x[i] < x_range[1] then extremes[1] elseif x[i] > x_range[2] then extremes[2] else x[i] for i in 1:n};